# customized array with default value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to costruct a custimzed array - which has some properties - and which has two possibilites.

The first when I DO NOT add index, then return a a specified value, something like this:

```
// in this case I would like to return the 0 index item
Debug.Print(spca)
```

but in this case:

```
// in this case it will return the 1 index item fo the array
Debug.Print(spca[1])
```

and in this case:

```
//will return the 2 index item fo the array
Debug.Print(spca[2])
```

So the concept is if I would like to reach the 0 index item, it can be done without index input.

Comment: Why? What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Yes, this could certainly be done. But, what is the use case, and would this be confusing to other developers? Are you really adding any value here?

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. It can be done using an implicit conversion operator, but that goes directly against the [recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) *"In general, implicit conversion operators should never throw exceptions and never lose information so that they can be used safely without the programmer's awareness. If a conversion operator cannot meet those criteria, it should be marked explicit."*. Even an explicit conversion is still bad.

Comment: array index starts at 0 so spca[1] wil return second item and spca[2] will return third item.

Comment: In the code, I have two handle two different cases. In the first, I need only the 0 index item, in the second, I need 1,2 indexed item. But for the clear-state, if I only need the 0 index item, I don't want that array structure appears in the logic layer, only where it's required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not be done using only an array. You'd need to create your own class and an indexer property `public ... this[int index]`.

However, the requirement of using the first value if no index is given can not be solved, as this would be equal to "not calling a method", which can not be done.

---

Based on the comments by `crashmstr` you could try the following (I currently cant test it, but you should get it to work):

```
public class SpecialArray
{
    private int[] m_theArray;

    public SpecialArray(int size)
    {
        m_theArray = new int[size];
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return m_theArray[index]; }
        set { m_theArray[index] = value; }
    }

    // Please note that this override is NOT INTUITIVE TO THE USER
    // Who would expect that the string representation of the array
    // might be the string representation of its first element?
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_theArray[0].ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator int(SpecialArray a)
    {
        return m_theArray[0];
    }
}
```

With this class, the following should work:

```
SpecialArray arr = new SpecialArray(5);
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 9;
arr[2] = 8;
arr[3] = 7;
arr[4] = 6;

int elemZero = arr; // equal to arr[0]
int elemOne = arr[1];
...
```

Comment: Why could this not be done with a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/85w54y0a.aspx)?

Comment: Interesting approach - wouldn't you still need a cast?

Comment: The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/85w54y0a.aspx) talks about implicit and explicit operators. *implicit* does not require a cast.

Comment: It's quite good but I have to always pass the default(0) item of this array to another variable before usage, like int elemZero = arr, it's okay, but if I would like to use directly arr, it's not working at all, or I missed something...

Comment: Define what you mean by *use directly arr*. The above solution works whenever `arr` is being implicitly cast to `int`. If you want to only output the values in `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine` you need to add the `ToString` override. Going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  public class spca
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var spacs = new spca();
      spacs[0] = "t";
      spacs[1] = "tt";
      spacs[1] = "ttt";

      // this will call the overritten Tostring and deliver first value
      Console.WriteLine(spacs);
      Console.WriteLine(spacs[1]);
      Console.WriteLine(spacs[2]);
    }

    private Dictionary<int, string> _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return _innerDictionary[0];
    }

    public object this[int key]
    {
      get
      {
        if (_innerDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) return _innerDictionary[key];

        return null;
      }

      set
      {
        _innerDictionary[key] = (string)value;

      }

    }
  }
```